# task node in AWS EMR copy data over from core nodes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mapreduce, emr, amazon-emr

I am trying to understand few key concepts for mapreduce, particularity when it pertains to AWS EMR.  Lets say for all of this i am using an external hive metastore(RDS)

My questions are as follows

- As EMR has a concept of Task node(which process data but do not hold persistent data from what i understand).  Is it copying the data over from HDFS(from core nodes) to the task node to do the processing and sending the end results back to core node.  I guess i am little bit confused due to the fact that mapredue is all about moving "the code" to where the data is for processing.  As Task node do not have any data on it, what is it processing(until and unless it copies over the data for processing as i mentioned earlier?)
- how does this work when all my data is sitting in S3, again the confused due to the fact, "code moves to data"...as my data is sitting in S3, is it copying it over to the core nodes for processing and putting things back in S3?
- If lets say I have all my data in S3, is it more efficient to use s3distcp to copy data over to HDFS for processing or am i better of pointing my hive tables to the S3 bucket location ?